# Automatic JSON serialization and deserialization of objects in Swift

Tags: json, serialization, swift

I'm looking for a way to automatically serialize and deserialize class instances in Swift. Let's assume we have defined the following class …

```
class Person {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

… and `Person` instance:

```
let person = Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe")
```

The JSON representation of `person` would be the following:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

Now, here are my questions:

1. How can I serialize the `person` instance and get the above JSON without having to manually add all properties of the class to a dictionary which gets turned into JSON?
2. How can I deserialize the above JSON and get back an instantiated object that is statically typed to be of type `Person`? Again, I don't want to map the properties manually.

---

Here's how you'd do that in C# using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json):

```
var person = new Person("John", "Doe");
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
// {"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}

Person deserializedPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
```

Comment: Generally in Swift/Objective-C, serialization will mean converting to `NSData` so the object can be stored as data rather than some plain-text format.

Comment: No need for 3rd party Json.NET here, DataContractJsonSerializer can do that.

Comment: @Agent_L I don't want to get too deeply into this debate here, but Newtonsoft.Json is a lot nicer to use and more feature-rich than `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

Comment: I'd vote you up another if I could just for using C#'s JSON.net as an (awesome) example!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As shown in [WWDC2017](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/102/) @ 24:48 (**Swift 4**), we will be able to use the Codable protocol. Example

```
public struct Person : Codable {
   public let firstName:String
   public let lastName:String
   public let location:Location
}
```

To serialize

```
let payload: Data = try JSONEncoder().encode(person)
```

To deserialize

```
let anotherPerson = try JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: payload)
```

Note that all properties must conform to the Codable protocol.

An **alternative** can be [JSONCodable](https://github.com/matthewcheok/JSONCodable) which is used by [Swagger's](http://swagger.io) code generator.

Comment: Is it possible to have a property like a dictionary as part of the struct and still use Codable? E.g. var items: [String: Any]? .  Would codable work in that case? I feel like, it will not.

Comment: Do you know if the `Codable` infrastructure can be reused for other encodings. A binary encoding in the style of Protocol Buffers, for example.

Comment: This is nice but how do you decode multiple items?  In the case when my payload contains an array of Person.self ?

Answer (score 20):

You could use [EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection) for that. You can use code like:

```
var person:Person = Person(json:jsonString)
```

or

```
var jsonString:String = person.toJsonString()
```

See the GitHub page for more detailed sample code. You only have to make EVObject the base class of your data objects. No mapping is needed (as long as the json keys are the same as the property names)

**Update:** Swift 4 has support for Codable which makes it almost as easy as EVReflection but with better performance. If you do want to use an easy contractor like above, then you could use this extension: [Stuff/Codable](https://github.com/evermeer/Stuff#codable)

Comment: Great, that is what I was looking for. Coming from C# and Ruby, parsing JSON was hell in iOS development.

Comment: EVReflection is beyond useful. Thank you so much

Answer (score 10):

With Swift 4, you simply have to make your class conform to `Codable` (`Encodable` and `Decodable` protocols) in order to be able to perform JSON serialization and deserialization.

```
import Foundation

class Person: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

*Usage #1 (encode a `Person` instance into a JSON string):*

```
let person = Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe")
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted // if necessary
let data = try! encoder.encode(person)
let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
print(jsonString)

/*
 prints:
 {
   "firstName" : "John",
   "lastName" : "Doe"
 }
 */
```

*Usage #2 (decode a JSON string into  a `Person` instance):*

```
let jsonString = """
{
  "firstName" : "John",
  "lastName" : "Doe"
}
"""

let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let person = try! decoder.decode(Person.self, from: jsonData)
dump(person)

/*
 prints:
 ▿ __lldb_expr_609.Person #0
   - firstName: "John"
   - lastName: "Doe"
 */
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a Foundation class called `NSJSONSerialization` which can do conversion to and from `JSON`.

The method for converting from JSON to an object looks like this:

```
let jsonObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, 
    options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, 
    error: &error) as NSDictionary
```

Note that the first argument to this method is the `JSON` data, but not as a string object, instead as a `NSData` object (which is how you'll often times get JSON data anyway).

You most likely will want a factory method for your class that takes JSON data as an argument, makes use of this method and returns an initialize object of your class.

To inverse this process and create JSON data out of an object, you'll want to make use of `dataWithJSONObject`, in which you'll pass an object that can be converted into JSON and have an `NSData?` returned.  Again, you'll probably want to create a helper method that requires no arguments as an instance method of your class.

---

As far as I know, the easiest way to handle this is to create a way to map your objects properties into a dictionary and pass that dictionary for turning your object into JSON data.  Then when turning your JSON data into the object, expect a dictionary to be returned and reverse the mapping process.  There may be an easier way though.

Comment: I know about `NSJSONSerialization` and working with dictionaries, but this is specifically *not* what I'm looking for. Doing all that manually is an error-prone way of writing boilerplate code which I'm trying to avoid here.

Comment: You can use `NSCoding` but it'll still require some boilerplate code. See: http://nshipster.com/nscoding/

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) library. It'll give you more control on variable names and the values and the prepared JSON. After adding this library extend the `Mappable` class and define `mapping(map: Map)` function.

For example

```
   class User: Mappable {
       var id: Int?
       var name: String?

       required init?(_ map: Map) {

       }

       // Mapping code
       func mapping(map: Map) {
          name    <- map["name"]
          id      <- map["id"]
       }

    }
```

Use it like below

```
   let user = Mapper<User>().map(JSONString)
```

Comment: All this does is add a nice syntax to the boilerplate code the OP is trying to avoid: writing a bunch of serialization steps for each property.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a Swift object like this

```
struct Person {
    var firstName: String?;
    var lastName: String?;
    init() {

    }
}
```

After that, serialize your JSON data you retrieved,   using the built-in ***NSJSONSerialization*** and parse the values into the ***Person*** object.

```
var person = Person();
var error: NSError?;
var response: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(), error: &error);

if let personDictionary = response as? NSDictionary {
    person.firstName = personDictionary["firstName"] as? String;
    person.lastName = personDictionary["lastName"] as? String;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Also please take a look at those libraries

[Swift-JsonSerialiser](https://github.com/gfx/Swift-JsonSerializer)

[ROJSONParser](https://github.com/prine/ROJSONParser)

Comment: This approach works, but it's not an answer to my question, I'm afraid. I was looking for a solution that **doesn't** require manually setting each property.

Comment: @MariusSchulz I think that answer "there is no such 1st party thing" is also an important answer, although it could be more clear here.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at NSKeyValueCoding.h, specifically `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary`.  Once you deserialize the json into a `NSDictionary`, you can then create and initialize your object with that dictionary instance, no need to manually set values on the object.  This will give you an idea of how the deserialization could work with json, but you will soon find out you need more control over deserialization process.  This is why I implement a category on `NSObject` which allows fully controlled `NSObject` initialization with a dictionary during json deserialization, it basically enriches the object even further than `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary` can do.  I also have a protocol used by the json deserializer, which allows the object being deserialized to control certain aspects, for example, if deserializing an NSArray of objects, it will ask that object what is the type name of the objects stored in the array.