# How to save AnyObject to sqlite3?

Tags: objective-c, swift, sqlite

I want to save objects of type AnyObject to sqlite3 database. Is it possible?
Maybe using blob?

Comment: You have to convert to respective type like as String, Int, Double etc. after that you have to save that object.

Comment: You want to save objective-c object into sqllite3 db right?in that case you can try serializing the object and save it in table column and deserialize it  to recreate object.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820720/automatic-json-serialization-and-deserialization-of-objects-in-swift