# Assigning a long JSON response to Dictionary produces a Thread error

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary

When trying to assign a long JSON response to a Dictionary, I get either

> nil

or

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Assigning a short response works fine. Here is my code

```
func getUserInfo() {
        let access_token : String = accessToken_json_response["access_token"] ?? "empty"
        if access_token != "empty" {
            Alamofire.request("https://api.github.com/user?access_token=\(access_token)").responseJSON { response in
                    if let json = response.result.value {
                        print(json) //The JSON prints, but takes more than a second to do so.   
                        self.getUser_json_response = json as? Dictionary<String, String> //This produces the thread error when the response is long.
                        print(self.getUser_json_response) //This either prints nil, or a thread error produces in the previous instruction
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to cast to json as? [String : Any]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you are casting to an optional dictionary so it should be conditional binding i.e:

```
if let unwrappedJson = json as? ....
```

Second, you should cast to `[String : Any]` i.e:

```
    if let unwrappedJson = json as? [String : Any]
```

Comment: This works, but why do I have to cast to [String: Any] and not [String:String]? (I've already done this previously with another json and it worked with the [String:String] cast)

Comment: I don't know the content of your data but to be on the safe side you should cast to [String : Any] and only then conditional bind the rest because a key could have a value of an array or another dictionary in it and String won't cut it...

Answer (score 1):

You have to serialise the response into json and then you can use it as dictionary.

`eg: let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]`

then print this json

Or

Use this link, this is latest update from apple to code and encode json response according to your class or model.

[Automatic JSON serialization and deserialization of objects in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820720/automatic-json-serialization-and-deserialization-of-objects-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

may this help..

```
Alamofire.request(UrlStr, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        print("JSON: \(JSON)")

                        let jsonResponse = (JSON as? [String:Any]) ?? [String:Any]()

                       print("jsonResponse: \(jsonResponse)")


                    }
                case .failure(let error):

                    print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```